# How can I handle authentication in android for a remote website?

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, codeigniter

I know I'm going to need authentication within an Android app I'm working on that will control shoutcast/icecast streams through an API.

What would you recommend?

Would it be easier to store the authentication within the app itself while a session is going on or rather have the user login each time?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever they start the app authenticate them and return a cookie from the server.  With every request they make send the cookie and make sure  they are still authenticated.  Set the expiration on the cookie to whenever you desire.